# How to integrate hyperexecute with selenium projects

Tags: selenium, testing, lambda

Im trying yo find a simillar way that integrating labda autoamtion run with existing selenium- testng tests by hyperexecute

Can somebody help !?!

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more